# Simple carousel using vw and a bit of jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I had some trouble working with bootstrp carousel so I decided to make a very simple one. In case it may help someone, I made a zip file [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sf9uLmG_nXZEhnYWc3bnVFZG8/view?usp=sharing)

I tested it on chrome and IE11, the sliding effect is not very good on IE but it works anyway.

Comment: And how can we help you?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: No question, I just shared it in case someone needs it. I didn't find another way than making a new question